# PL/SQL stored procedure loop compare value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am using using PLSQL to create an insert stored procedure to insert data to table `REGISTER` which has 2 input parameters `PR_START_FROM` and `PR_TO_END` and I want to compare the two new input parameters the the existing data as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

If the new input is not between record one then compare it to record two and if not between record two then compare to record the next record until end of record, if it between all of the record the return false, else return true.

This is my code in PLSQL that I tried:

```
create or replace procedure TEST_LOOP(
PR_START_FROM in varchar2,
PR_END in varchar2,
V_CURSOR out SYS_REFCURSOR) is
ROWAMOUT number;
STARTNUM number;
ENDNUM number;
ID number;
begin
  select count(*) into ROWAMOUT from REGISTER;
  for ID in 1..ROWAMOUT loop
    select START_FROM,TO_END into STARTNUM,ENDNUM from REGISTER where REGISTER_ID=ID;
    if (PR_START_FROM between STARTNUM and ENDNUM) and (PR_END between STARTNUM and ENDNUM) then 
      {statement....}
    else
      {statement....}
    end if;
  end loop;
end TEST_LOOP;
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Quite bad, why not `FOR aRow IN (SELECT * FROM REGISTER) LOOP`?

Answer (score 2):

You can check and return `true` or `false` string values through a single SQL Select statement by

```
select decode(sign(count(*)),1,'false','true') 
  from register
 where :PR_START_FROM between start_from and to_end 
    or :PR_TO_END between start_from and to_end
```

whether at least one of the bind variables stay in the range( if so, will return `false` )